# Page types are not ported using Content Porter with XPM aplication data check

Tags: web8, experience-manager, content-porter-web8

I'm trying to export the content types from one environment to another using Content Porter 8.5

Having the following structure:

[image]

When I export those items with the XPM option selected:

[image]

The settings for page type seems to not follow:

[image]

I'm just interested in "Structure" and "Content" dependencies, so I add them to the export/import.

I'm adding the items in a Bundle and then export/import the bundle content but since that approach do not work so I tried as described here without success.

Any ideas of what I'm missing?

Comment: I did a quick test it's working fine from my end, Please edit your questions and update your summary configuration file of export and import, you will get the end of the step before the start export/import?